# Discrete-time-dependent Hamiltonian from sequence of unitaries

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, time-evolution, discrete

Consider a system evolving in discrete time with the time evolution given by a some unitary operator $\hat{U}(t)$ that advances the system by one time step, i.e. $$\psi(t+1) = \hat{U}(t)\psi(t).$$ The evolution operator can be time-dependent, so the unitary stepping the system forward in time may change based on the time step, like for example $\hat{U}_1$ for all even time steps and $\hat{U}_2$ for all odd ones.

Clearly, this system can be time-dependent and it seems that it is fully described by the time evolution protocol. How would one get to the time-dependent Hamiltonian $\hat{H}(t)$ from this, though? And what is the time-dependent Schrödinger equation for a system that is discrete in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no unique way to find an associated Hamiltonian.

To illustrate my answer, I will consider the autonomous case ($U$ is constant) in a $n$-dimensional (finite) Hilbert space (e.g. spins, qbits...). It would be reasonable to expect that there is an associated constant Hamiltonian $H$, related to $U$ by:
$$
U = e^{-iH}
$$
To invert the expression, you'll need to define the logarithm of a unitary matrix. It is possible, but in general, it is multivalued. This is most easily seen by applying the spectral theorem on $U$. This reverts to the case when $U$ is diagonal:
$$
U = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{-ih_1} & 0& 0 \\
0 & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0& e^{-ih_n}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $h_1... h_n\in\mathbb R$. In this case, all the possible hamiltonians are of the form:
$$
H = \begin{pmatrix}
h_1+2\pi k_1 & 0& 0 \\
0 & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0& h_n+2\pi k_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $k_1... k_n\in\mathbb Z$. Therefore, even in this most simple case, there are many possible hamiltonians. Naturally, if $U$ is sufficiently close to the identity, namely:
$$
||U-I||<1
$$
then there is a natural candidate given by the power series expansion of the logarithm (analogue of the principal branch):
$$
H = i\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(U-I)^n
$$

In the non autonomous case, there are even more possibilities. If you let $H$ vary during each discrete tilmestep, the possibilities countless, it's like asking for the velocity of someone going from one point to another. If you don't know the taken path, I can be anything. The analogue of constant velocity would be one of constant Hamiltonian. In this case, you just need o apply the previous reasoning to each time step.

For the Schrödinger equation, the natural analogue is the equation you wrote:
$$
\psi(t+1) = U(t)\psi(t)
$$

Note that in any case, since the hamiltonian is arbitrary, it is best to stick to $U$ when computing anything relevant.

Hope this helps.